# атрибут defer и механизм $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Какая разница между использованием:

- атрибута *defer* в `<script>` (для загрузки скрипта после загрузки страницы)
- инструмента window.onload = function(){}
- и такой популярной конструкции `$(document).ready(function(){ какой-то скрипт})` в jQuery???

Поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь, но вроде как во всех этих случаях результат одинаковый, а именно: загрузка скрипта после загрузки страницы.

Comment: А как же `window.onload = function(){}`?

Comment: да, согласен еще и такой вариант есть, добавил

Comment: Defer неправильно работает в IE<=9  https://github.com/h5bp/lazyweb-requests/issues/42

Comment: Возможно ипользуют jQuery, т.к. привыкли, defer с 2010 года только стал поддерживаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defer можно только для js файлов применять

Comment: @lNaydI моего ответа недостаточно?

Comment: А какие еще могут быть варианты файлов? Получается если подключаешь JS то все 3 варианта равноценны?

Comment: @lNaydI window.onload можно использовать в HTML без создания отдельного js файла.